# Is it possible to push data from database into a table in a .docx file?

Tags: java, docx

Very specific: Using Java, I would like to produce a table in `.docx` format  from the data I have in a database, without needing a word template.

Is there a way to do this without the need to create a template or to create something in the wordfile beforehand?

Comment: docx is a zip file containing some xmls. If you want to bother reading the docx spec, you can simply generate the xmls yourself and then zip em up.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a document from scratch without a template.

You have to use libraries like Apache Poi or Docx4j

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your data to XML, you can use XSLT to transform it to Flat OPC XML.  Word can read that, or you can use docx4j to convert it to a docx file.